# How can I calculate the value (from csv file) between one row and the next and so on using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is for a homework. I have to calculate values in the second column of my excel sheet. I need to subtract row one from row two then row two from row three and so on. Then add the results to a list so I can find the greatest and lowest value. For some reason, my code is not printing it. What I am doing wrong?

```
listcsvreader = list(csvreader)
i = 0
change = 0
listcolumnvalue = []
while i in range(len(listcsvreader)):
    change = float(listcsvreader[i + 1][1]) - float(listcsvreader[i][1])
    i = i + 1
    listcolumnvalue = listcolumnvalue.append(change)

print(listcolumnvalue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- `append` changes the list in place. It does not return a new list.
- Use `len(listcsvreader)-1` so the index does not go past the array edge

Try this code:

```
import csv

ss = '''
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
'''.strip()

with open('tmp.csv', 'w') as f: f.write(ss)

############

f = open('tmp.csv')
csvreader = csv.reader(f)

listcsvreader = list(csvreader)
i = 0
change = 0
listcolumnvalue = []
while i in range(len(listcsvreader)-1):
    change = float(listcsvreader[i + 1][1]) - float(listcsvreader[i][1])
    i = i + 1
    listcolumnvalue.append(change)

print(listcolumnvalue)
```

Output

```
[3.0, 3.0]
```

-- UPDATE --

Based on the latest comment, the text file is not a CSV, but a list. This can easily be processed using the `eval` function:

```
ss = '''
[['Jan-2010', '867884'], ['Aug-2016', '569899'], ['Sep-2016', '768450'], ['Oct-2016', '102685'], ['Nov-2016', '795914'], ['Dec-2016', '60988'], ['Jan-2017', '138230'], ['Feb-2017', '671099']]
'''.strip()

with open('tmp.csv', 'w') as f: f.write(ss)  # write test file


############

with open('tmp.csv') as f:
   s = f.read()
lst = eval(s)  # convert string to python list

lst = [[x[0],int(x[1])] for x in lst]  # convert numbers from strings

i = 0
change = 0
listcolumnvalue = []
while i in range(len(lst)-1):
    change = float(lst[i + 1][1]) - float(lst[i][1])
    i = i + 1
    listcolumnvalue.append(change)

print(listcolumnvalue)
```

Output

```
[-297985.0, 198551.0, -665765.0, 693229.0, -734926.0, 77242.0, 532869.0]
```

Comment: It's so weird! It's still returning an empty list for me.

Comment: My csvreader is a list of list. Would that make a difference?

Comment: What is the format of the CSV?   Please update your post so I can check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import csv

csvpath = os.path.join("..", "Resources", "budget_data.csv")

with open(csvpath) as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(csvreader)  

    listcsvreader = list(csvreader)
    i = 0
    change = 0
    listcolumnvalue = []
    while i in range(len(listcsvreader)-1):
         change = float(listcsvreader[i + 1][1]) - float(listcsvreader[i][1])
         i = i + 1
         listcolumnvalue.append(change)

    print(listcolumnvalue)
```

This is what the csvfile looks like:

[['Jan-2010', '867884'],  ['Aug-2016', '569899'], ['Sep-2016', '768450'], ['Oct-2016', '102685'], ['Nov-2016', '795914'], ['Dec-2016', '60988'], ['Jan-2017', '138230'], ['Feb-2017', '671099']]